# What is the most efficient way to relay a directory tree through tcp? c++

Tags: c++, tcp, tree, directory

I'm trying to send a directory tree structure over TCP.  The tree could possibly in sub directories.  I don't want to send the actual contents, but more or less send a listing in one stream of bytes.  What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: Ask yourself this - what's the most efficient way to pack that tree into an array of bytes. After that it'd be easy.

Comment: I wouldn't agree with that.  He'll have to worry about endianness, byte packing, etc. if he uses a byte-buffer to transmit.  This is fine if he understands that though :) it'll certainly be the most efficient way data-size wise.

Comment: If "most efficient" means "fewest lines of new code per feature delivered", here is a fairly efficient solution: `dup2(socket_fd, 0); dup2(socket_fd, 1); execlp("ls", "ls", "-R", dirname, (char*)0);`

Comment: @Rob: Haha, nice joke (I hope).  Now let's see the code on the reading side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet for efficiency (I'm going to assume you mean you're looking for a solution that will require sending a small number of bytes relative to other solutions), readability, and portability is something like [JSON](http://www.json.org/).

```
{"dir":"/","children":
  [{"dir":"bin","children":
     [{"file":"bash"},
      {"file":"csh"}]
   },
   {"dir":"home","children":null}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

To send a tree, just recursively do the following:

Send the root, and then its children.

Answer (score 0):

The "best" has alot of interpretations depending on the scenario.  If you can provie a format that makes it easier for your clients (the TCP receivers) to make use of your data, then that's probably a good idea.

Usually I think of the best as being most understandable way.  For example, an XML representation would be good because XML is everywhere - everyone knows it (or they should).  There's a million COTS libraries that handle it, and its well known.

XML also inherently can make entities contain other entities, and has parent/child between nodes by default - so the format will mirror a directory structure very well.

The down-side to xml is that it is very verbose.  You could construct a flat-file format that would be much smaller if you're willing to handle the extra complexity (and file size cam really matter in a network application).  If you're going for the flat-file representation, consider how you would structure data in a single database table (name, file/folder, parent_directory, etc).